# Javascript slider changes behavior when using zoom css property

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, touch

We have a a circular slider built with javascript and css. We need the slider to support touch and mouse events. The slider respond to mousemove/touchmove events properly. It still acts as expected when zooming in/out using Chrome zoom functionality, but it starts to act weird when we add and manipulate Zoom css property within its container.

Working slider: http://jsfiddle.net/sCanr/1/

To reproduce: 
1) add  (style="zoom:0.5") to the container tag, so it would be:

```
<div id='container'  style="zoom:0.5"> 
<div id='slider'> </div>
</div>
```

2) try moving the handler with mouse. (touchmove event produce similar behavior)

Note: we have to work with Zoom css property, as we are inserting our slider into a container maintained by different team, which uses the zoom property.

Comment: Tell the "different team", that they shouldn't use the non-standard [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [jQuery roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin, where the problem was resolved. Also no need to handle lot of codes in the application.

Check the below demo:

## [**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/qua2hp2z/)